# Typescript Cannot write file would overwrite input file. Error when compiling Ionic 3 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I've been trying to use a given .js api in an ionic 3 project. With some help I was able to get the api into to the project without any errors and am now able to use the functions it has. However the API uses `JQuery 2.1.0` and now when compiling the project I get the following error: `Cannot write file '.../src/assets/jquery-2.1.0.min.js' because it would overwrite input file.` I have no idea on how to fix this.. I've tried to import the jquery file as a module but that gives me some errors as well. Both the api.ts and jquery-2.1.0.min.js are in the `src/assets/` folder and then the api is imported in my `src/pages/home/home.ts` file.

This is the api.ts:

```
import * as $ from './jquery-2.1.0.min.js';

export class API {
  ServerUrl = '';

  Type = {
    Day: 'day',
    Night: 'night'
  };

  Days = {
    Monday: 'Monday',
    Tuesday: 'Tuesday',
    Wednesday: 'Wednesday',
    Thursday: 'Thursday',
    Friday: 'Friday',
    Saturday: 'Saturday',
    Sunday: 'Sunday'
  };

  MinTemperature = parseFloat('5.0');
  MaxTemperature = parseFloat('30.0');
  MaxSwitches = 5;

  Time;
  CurrentDay;
  DayTemperature;
  NightTemperature;
  CurrentTemperature;
  TargetTemperature;
  ProgramState;

  Program:any = {};

  constructor() {
    this.Program[this.Days.Monday]    = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Tuesday]   = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Wednesday] = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Thursday]  = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Friday]    = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Saturday]  = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Sunday]    = [];
  }

  /* Retrieve day program
   */
  getProgram(day) {
    return this.Program[day];
  }

  /* Sorts the heating periods (the periods when the heating is on) and merges overlapping ones
   */
  sortMergeProgram(day) {
    let program = this.getProgram(day);
    program.sort(function(a, b) {
      return this.parseTime(a[0]) - this.parseTime(b[0])
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < program.length - 1; i++) {
      if (this.parseTime(program[i][1]) >= this.parseTime(program[i + 1][0])) {
        let start = (program[i][0]);
        let end = (this.parseTime(program[i][1]) > this.parseTime(program[i + 1][1])) ? program[i][1] : program[i + 1][1];
        program.splice(i, 2);
        program.push([start, end]);
        this.sortMergeProgram(day);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  /* Retrieves all data from the server except for weekProgram
   */
  get(attribute_name, xml_tag) {
    return this.requestData(
      "/" + attribute_name,
      function(data) {
        return $(data).find(xml_tag).text();
      }
    );
  }

  /* Retrieves the week program
   */
  getWeekProgram() {
    return this.requestData(
      '/weekProgram',
      function(data) {
        $(data).find('day').each(function() {
          let day = (<any>$(this)).attr('name');
          this.Program[day] = [];
          $(this).find('switch').each(function() {
            if ((<any>$(this)).attr('state') == 'on') {
              if ((<any>$(this)).attr('type') == this.Type.Day) {
                this.getProgram(day).push([$(this).text(), '00:00']);
              } else {
                this.getProgram(day)[this.getProgram(day).length - 1][1] = $(this).text();
              }
            }
          })
        });
        return this.Program;
      }
    );
  }

  /* Uploads all data to the server except for currentTemperature and weekProgram
   */
  put(attribute_name, xml_tag, value) {
    this.uploadData("/" + attribute_name, "<" + xml_tag + ">" + value + "</" + xml_tag + ">");
  }

  requestData(address, func) {
    let result;
    (<any>$).ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: this.ServerUrl + address,
      dataType: "xml",
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        result = func(data);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }

  /* Uploads the week program
   */
  setWeekProgram() {
    let doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, null, null);
    let program = doc.createElement('week_program');
    program.setAttribute('state', this.ProgramState ? 'on' : 'off');
    for (let key in this.Program) {
      let day = doc.createElement('day');
      day.setAttribute('name', key);

      let daySwitches = [];
      let nightSwitches = [];

      let i, text, sw;
      let periods = this.getProgram(key);
      for (i = 0; i < periods.length; i++) {
        daySwitches.push(periods[i][0]);
        nightSwitches.push(periods[i][1]);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < this.MaxSwitches; i++) {
        sw = doc.createElement('switch');
        sw.setAttribute('type', this.Type.Day);

        if (i < daySwitches.length) {
          sw.setAttribute('state', 'on');
          text = doc.createTextNode(daySwitches[i]);
        } else {
          sw.setAttribute('state', 'off');
          text = doc.createTextNode('00:00');
        }
        sw.appendChild(text);
        day.appendChild(sw);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < this.MaxSwitches; i++) {
        sw = doc.createElement('switch');
        sw.setAttribute('type', this.Type.Night);

        if (i < nightSwitches.length) {
          sw.setAttribute('state', 'on');
          text = doc.createTextNode(nightSwitches[i]);
        } else {
          sw.setAttribute('state', 'off');
          text = doc.createTextNode('00:00');
        }
        sw.appendChild(text);
        day.appendChild(sw);
      }
      program.appendChild(day);
    }
    doc.appendChild(program);
    this.uploadData('/weekProgram', (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc));
  }

  /* Creates the default week program
   */
  setDefault() {
    let doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, null, null);
    let program = doc.createElement('week_program');
    program.setAttribute('state', this.ProgramState ? 'on' : 'off');
    for (let key in this.Program) {
      let day = doc.createElement('day');
      day.setAttribute('name', key);

      let daySwitches = [];
      let nightSwitches = [];

      let i, text, sw;

      for (i = 0; i < this.MaxSwitches; i++) {
        sw = doc.createElement('switch');
        sw.setAttribute('type', this.Type.Night);
        sw.setAttribute('state', 'off');
        text = doc.createTextNode('00:00');
        sw.appendChild(text);
        day.appendChild(sw);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < this.MaxSwitches; i++) {
        sw = doc.createElement('switch');
        sw.setAttribute('type', this.Type.Day);
        sw.setAttribute('state', 'off');
        text = doc.createTextNode('00:00');
        sw.appendChild(text);
        day.appendChild(sw);
      }

      program.appendChild(day);
    }
    doc.appendChild(program);
    this.uploadData('/weekProgram', (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc));
  }

  uploadData(address, xml) {
    (<any>$).ajax({
      type: "put",
      url: this.ServerUrl + address,
      contentType: 'application/xml',
      data: xml,
      async: false
    });
  }

  parseTime(t) {
    return parseFloat(t.substr(0, 2)) + parseFloat(t.substr(3, 2)) / 60;
  }

  /* Adds a heating period for a specific day
   */
  addPeriod(day, start, end) {
    let program = this.getWeekProgram()[day];
    program.push([start, end]);
    this.sortMergeProgram(day);
    this.setWeekProgram();
  }

  /* Removes a heating period from a specific day.
     idx is the idex of the period with values from 0 to 4
  */
  removePeriod(day, idx) {
    let program = this.getWeekProgram()[day];
    let start = program[idx][0];
    let end = program[idx][1];
    program.splice(idx, 1);
    this.setWeekProgram();
  }

  /* Checks whether the temperature is within the range [5.0,30.0]
   */
  inTemperatureBoundaries(temp) {
    temp = parseFloat(temp);
    return (temp >= this.MinTemperature && temp <= this.MaxTemperature);
  }
}
```

And this is the [jquery-2.1.0.js](https://pastebin.com/DsX9i240) that was provided (pastebin link since the file is too large, it is very large).

I have already edited my `tsconfig.json` to also have `"allowJs"= true,` in there.

Is there anyone who know how I could possibly fix this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by not using the jquery.js file but instead by importing jquery. Following this tutorial: https://x-team.com/blog/include-javascript-libraries-in-an-ionic-2-typescript-project/ but instead using the jquery-2.1.0 version from npm! After I just imported jquery in the following way: `import * as $ from 'jquery';` and everything works fine!!

Comment: dont use it. Seriously if it does not has a none jquery import then find something else , thats a heavy bit of extra code for a mobile app

Comment: It's for a school assignment that in which I **have** to use this API. If this were a real app I would public I'd prolly not use this or rewrite the whole API myself but this whole assignment is focused on user interfaces. The functionality is only there so that the professors can test it. And since this is only about the interface I feel like I've already spend way more time on the API than necessary. So if this works for now I'm more than happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the Typescript declaration (.d.ts) files that is confusing the compiler.

First run this command to delete all old declaration files the tsc has generated:

```
find . -type f -name "*.d.ts" -delete
```

Then change your `tsconfig.json` to have

```js
"compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm on windows so that command doesn't work, manually looking for all *.d.ts files and and deleting them results in the `cannot find module "/.build"` error.